# the amalgamation property

Tags: model-theory

*Definitions*:

- The *age* of a structure $M$ is the class of finitely generated substructures of $M$.
- A class of structures K has the *amalgamation property* (AP) if

> Whenever $A,B,C$  belong to $K$ and $e:A \to B$, $f:A \to C$ are embeddings, then there is a $D$ belonging to $K$ and embeddings $g:B \to D$, $h:C \to D$ such that $g \circ e = h \circ f$.

Give a direct argument showing that the age of the complete (undirected) graph $K_n$ satisfies the amalgamation property.

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: I edited your question to include $\LaTeX$ commands.  Please check that it still reflects your original intent.

Comment: Can you include a bit more of the context?  What is the *age* of a graph?

Comment: The only age of a model M that I know of is the class of finitely generated submodels of M. Is this where we're playing ball Safiya?

Comment: Yes.it is home work.

Comment: The age of kn is  kn,  n belongs to N. N is natural number.

Comment: @safiya: I believe Sammy Black was looking for the general definition of age. I've edited to include this definition. Are you sure that the question is correctly stated? For any particular $n$, the age of $K_n$ is the set of complete graphs $\{K_m | m\leq n\}$, which does not have the amalgamation property.